# Open Source библиотека для чтения .doc файлов

Tags: c#, .net, doc

На просторах интернета довольно большое количество библиотек, предоставляющих возможность работы с MS Word 2007 -  файлами.

Но задача заключается в парсинге в текстовый формат .doc файлов, попытки поиска таких библиотек под .net не увенчались успехом: библиотеки либо платные изначально, либо предоставляется ограниченная бесплатная лицензия, позволяющая распарсить документ размером не больше чем сколько то параграфов.

В идеале требования к библиотеке следующие : 
1. Бесплатное использование в любых целях. 
2. Отсутсвует привязка к файловой системе

Изначально произвел поиск в NuGet, покопался в библиотеках GemBox, Spire.Doc и подобных. Оказалось, что бесплатная лицензия является сильно лимитированной и у первого решения бесплатная лицензия предоставляет возможность извлечения текста из .doc только в размере 20 параграфов, вторая библиотека -- Spire.Doc -- позволяет вычитать 100 параграфов. Ничего интересного в NuGet для чтения .doc более не нашлось. Пошерстив интернеты, наткнулся на много исключительно платных решений, или решений  с лимитированной лицензией. Назрел вопрос, есть ли какие free-аналоги

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами предоставить рекомендации или найти книги, инструменты, библиотеки, материалы для обучения или любые другие внешние ресурсы являются на Stack Overflow вопросами не по теме, так как приводят к спорам и спаму. Вместо этого опишите проблему и что вы сделали для её решения.

Comment: @Regent спасибо за уточнение!

Comment: @ValeriyBelokurov: Но вы всё же дополните вопрос, а то его заморозят.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с doc можно использовать открытую библиотеку от Microsoft [OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/).

Взять весь текст можно так:

```
    public string ReadWordDocument()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var element = package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
        if (element == null) { return string.Empty; }

        this.AppendPlainText(element, sb);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public void AppendPlainText(OpenXmlElement element, StringBuilder sb)
    {
        foreach (var section in element.Elements())
        {
            switch (section.LocalName)
            {
                // Text 
                case "t":
                    sb.Append(section.InnerText);
                    break;


                case "cr":                          // Carriage return 
                case "br":                          // Page break 
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    break;


                // Tab 
                case "tab":
                    sb.Append("\t");
                    break;


                // Paragraph 
                case "p":
                    this.AppendPlainText(section, sb);
                    sb.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    break;


                default:
                    this.AppendPlainText(section, sb);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

В моей версии не создаются лишние объекты StringBuilder. Исходник [тут](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSOpenXmlGetPlainText-554918c3#content).

Comment: разве OpenXml не с .docx работает, как следует из названия?

Comment: npoi попробуйте

Comment: NPoi так же не работает с .doc, несмотря на то, что в NuGet в сводке указано , что формат поддерживается.